# set a range, then concate range to a single cell on another sheet with a row above each consolidated cell

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, concatenation

I'm trying to take the range of A5-A(last row), then on another sheet make a ##note row, and insert the concrete cell of each row below it. after the new rows have been combined and set in the second sheet, clear that range that was copied over from the first sheet.

I was looking into how to use the concrete function here because I needed a space in between the cells as they're being combined, so i thought to use this formula:

```
=CONCAT(" ",textjoin(" ", 1, A5:5))
```

but I don't know how to implement that function within google script. Also, I wanted to have a cell above it that has "## note line" so I believe that has to be looped in that code somehow as well.

here is a visual of what I am trying to do

[image]

Then put it into another sheet like this:

[image]

and this is where i got stuck on the code:

```java
function sendRowsToOtherTab()
{
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var eddGenSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Eddie Input Generator");
  var lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet = eddGenSheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var lcwithcontentofEddGenSheet = eddGenSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheet2= ss.getSheetByName("Combo Page");
  
  //Current combo Variables 
  var totalcurrentstringRows = lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet-4;
  var fullcurrentString = eddGenSheet.getRange(5,1,totalcurrentstringRows, lcwithcontentofEddGenSheet);
  var cslastRow = fullcurrentString.getLastRow();
 var bottomrightcolumnNumber = eddGenSheet.getRange(lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet - 1, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
 //This is where the date needs to start being sent to
 var insercellsstartingHere= sheet2.getrange("B19");
```

Im new to loops and coding and i don't even see a concate action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myfunc101()  {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const tsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  tsh.clearContents();
  const rg=sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow()-4,sh.getLastRow());
  const vs=rg.getDisplayValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{tsh.appendRow([`## ${i+1} notes`]);tsh.appendRow(r);});
}

function myfunc102()  {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const tsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  tsh.clearContents();
  const rg=sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow()-4,sh.getLastRow());
  const vs=rg.getDisplayValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{tsh.appendRow([`## ${i+1} notes`]);tsh.appendRow([r.join(' ')]);});
}
```

This will clear B19 to bottom of sheet and then post results there

```
function myfunc103()  {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const tsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  tsh.getRange(19,2,tsh.getLastRow()-18,1).clearContent();
  const rg=sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow()-4,sh.getLastRow());
  const vs=rg.getDisplayValues();
  let oA=[];
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{oA.push([`## ${i+1} notes`]);oA.push([r.join(' ')]);});
  tsh.getRange(19,2,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Comment: very close to what I am looking for, the only thing is I am also trying to combine the columns into one cell for each row with space in between as they are added together. right now this gets the cells over to the page and with the notes, but they aren't sent as single cells

Comment: Try the second one but don't allow the cell to wrap

Comment: perfect, I got it working.if I want to change the spot that it starts, I just change the tsh location via setting a range to the row I'd want, right?

Comment: Where do you want it to start? Do you have some header rows?

Comment: the goal is b19 on sheet 2

Comment: Do you have header infomation above that?

Comment: yes, just basic stuff that is manually inserted. thank you so much. I'll do some research on the actions you called to hopefully understand more of it

Comment: I think the latest version will do everything you need

Comment: The Array Methods are very useful.  Well worth the time to learn them.  I was kind of a old school javascript guy when I first volunteered here but a lot of the other volunteers use them a lot.  Them and arrow notation are still fairly new to me.  Oh maybe you were talking about setValues() ... that's the way to load data to a whole range at one time.

Comment: wow are the "let, for each and push" statements part of the array methods?? and I think I get set value for what I do as of now